# Cheapest High Available Web Server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, high-availability, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

I would like to create a high-available setup (e.g. a small cluster) for a webserver, i.e. it will run Apache, PHP and MySQL.

There will be between 2-8 small websites running with only very little traffic and workload. High availability is however very important.

I don't want to be dependent on 1 datacenter, so there must be a minimum of 2 servers placed in different datacenters, and if one server goes down, the user must experience no or only a minimum of downtime - and no data loss.

I have considered Amazon AWS using their Elastic Load Balancing, since it is possible to buy 2 EC2 instances in 2 availability zones and set up load balancing and RDS (Multi-AZ).

However this seems rather expensive. Using the AWS price calculator http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html it totals to 185$/month the first year (including the free tier).

Are my calculations incorrect or is there a cheaper way to make this HA setup?

Best regards

Comment: If you can't justify $185/month for high-availability, your app doesn't *need* high-availability.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: Hi. I see the problem! I will look into the rules and FAQ, so I don't make a similar mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry cheap and high-available aren't two words that have ever gone together. You get what you pay for and generally speaking a service like AWS is going to be the cheapest option you can get if you use a reserved instance.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. I guess this is the way to go then. Thanks for you answer.